# Optimally and elegantly performing certain behaviors based on types in a hierarchy

Tags: c#, performance, type-conversion, hierarchy, overloading

I am trying to optimize a certain part of my code, which happens to be in a tight performance loop. Mainly I am trying to learn new things which I can apply in the future. My implementation is very lengthy, so I will give a general example of what I am trying to achieve.

My question relates to this: [C# 'is' operator performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686412/c-sharp-is-operator-performance), and especially to the chosen answer.

Say I have a class A. I also have a class B, which is derived from A. I have a list of type A (which contains a mix of A and B types). In a method where I process these items, I would like to achieve a certain behaviour based on the actual type of the object (not sure if this is the correct way of saying it. Please correct me wherever I say something wrong).

```
void Process(A item)
{
   if (item is A)
   {
      DoBehavior((A)item); //I know the cast is redundant here, I'm just leaving 
                           //it here for my explanation.
   }
   else if (item is B)
   {
      DoBehavior((B)item);
   }
}

void DoBehaviour(A item)
{
   //perform necessary behaviour for type A
}

void DoBehaviour(B item)
{
   //perform necessary behaviour for type B
}
```

This is the way I currently do it. Note that I iterate over a list of type A, which contains A's and B's. Also, if you feel I did not provide enough code to clarify the situation, I'll gladly expand.

In the question I posted above: [C# 'is' operator performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686412/c-sharp-is-operator-performance), I have learnt that I can rather change the structure to use an "as" operator, and completely get rid of the explicit cast.

```
B bItem = item as B;

if (bItem  != null)
{
    DoBehavior(bItem);
}
```

This is all good, however, in actuality I do not just have an A and a B, I also have a C, a D, and so on, all deriving from base class A. This will lead to many of these if statements, and they would have to be nested for best performance:

```
B bItem = item as B;

if (bItem  != null)
{
    DoBehavior(bItem);
}
else
{
   C cItem = item as C;
   if (cItem != null)
   {
      DoBehavior(cItem);
   }
   else
   {
      //and so on.
   }
}
```

Now this is ugly. I like writing neat, elegant code, yet I am exceptionally bad at doing it (which often leads me to wasting time trying to just make things look a little better).

I hope this question is not to broad, but firstly I would like to know if there is a more optimal and clean solution at getting the type so that the relevant behavior is performed. If not, is there a cleaner way to use these 'as' operators than nesting it like this?

I suppose one alternative would be to move the behavior into the base class A, and then overriding it for each derived class. However, in a higher thinking sense, the behavior in this particular case of mine is not a behavior of the class A (or it's children), rather, it is some external class acting/behaving on it (which will behave differently for each type). If there is no better way to do it, I will strongly consider implementing it as I have explained now - but I would like some expert opinions on this.

I tried to keep this short, and may have left too much detail out. Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: This looks like a good place to implement the visitor pattern.

Comment: That first cast isn't redundant at all!

Comment: I just learnt about the visitor pattern 5 minutes ago, from a related question I had.

Comment: I decided to go for the visitor pattern and it works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for the situation I found is to use a Double-Dispatch/Visitor pattern. I describe a situation where base class A is abstract, and concrete classes B and C inherit from A. Also, by making the DoBehavior method in the base class A abstract, we are forcing ourselves to make an implementation for it wherever we would need it, so if we expand this to add more types, we won't forget to add it's DoBehavior methods (seems unlikely that one would forget, but this behavior may be insignificant to the rest of the new type you add, and may be overlooked - especially if there are many of these behavior patterns)

```
interface IVisitor
{
   void DoBehavior(B item);
   void DoBehavior(C item);
}

abstract class A
{
    abstract void DoBehavior(IVisitor visitor);
}

class B : A
{
    override void DoBehavior(IVisitor visitor)
    {
       //can do some internal behavior here    
       visitor.DoBehavior(this); //external processing
    }
}

class C : A
{
    override void DoBehavior(IVisitor visitor)
    {
       //can do some internal behavior here   
       visitor.DoBehavior(this); //external processing
    }
}


class Manager: IVisitor //(or executor or whatever. The external processing class)
{

    public static void ProcessAll(List<A> items)
    {
        foreach(A item in items)
        {
            item.DoBehavior(this);
        }
    }

   void DoBehavior(B item)
   {

   }

   void DoBehavior(C item);
   { 

   }

}
```

Thanks for contributing, everyone. Learnt a lot and got some good ideas from you all (it's worth it to read all the answers if you face a similar situation).

Comment: I can only do that in 2 days for some reason. Thanks though. Following on what you did and reading up really helped me get to this final solution, and your own solution and earlier mistakes solidified my understanding of method overloading and OOP in general.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what polymorphism is all about ? A method that has different behavior depending on its type. And I'm fairly sure this would be faster than a "type switch".
And if you need to, you can also use function overloading (for your external processing), see the test program below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class A
{
    public String Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public A()
    {
        Value = "A's value";
    }

    public virtual void Process()
    {
        // Do algorithm for type A
        Console.WriteLine("In A.Process()");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Health
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public B()
    {
        Value = "B's value";
        Health = 100;
    }

    public override void Process()
    {
        // Do algorithm for type B
        Console.WriteLine("In B.Process()");
    }
}

public static class Manager
{
    // Does internal processing
    public static void ProcessInternal(List<A> items)
    {
        foreach(dynamic item in items)
        {
            item.Process(); // Call A.Process() or B.Process() depending on type
            ProcessExternal(item);
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessExternal(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
    }

    public static void ProcessExternal(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.Health);
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List<A> objects = new List<A>();
        objects.Add(new A());
        objects.Add(new B());
        ProcessInternal(objects);
    }
}
```

**Note that this will only work with .Net 4.0 !**

Comment: In my suggested solution I mention doing this, yet as I explained, the process is rather external to the class. I'll see if I can implement this while keeping some sense in my code. To give you an exact explanation of what I'm doing, I am looping through a list of entities (zombies, animals, objects, people, etc) from my game, and deleting them (this is for when they need to be destroyed). The deletion process has an internal part, which is handled already, and an external part, which is handled by my data structure manager. The data structure is in reality more complex than just a list...

Comment: hence I use a manager (its a 2D array of dictionaries of bucket objects of different linked lists, one for each type of entity). Hence I need separate deletion processes for each. Now I can handled this internally to the entities, but I feel it rather belongs in the manager's class. Yet discussing this with you drove me closer to your answer. I'm thinking of letting the data manager pass itself to a process function in the entity itself. That would remove all conditional logic, and eliminate the need for type checking. Most simple = most genius, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover both, internal and external processing cases.

Comment: Does the overloading actually work in this case?? I thought it would be compiled to always call ProcessExternal(A a) in this case?

Comment: I've just tried it and it produced:
In A.Process()
A
In B.Process()
B so it's definitely calling the overload.

Comment: Yes I tried it as well now. It's very good! Thank you. I am dumbfounded by why I didn't try this.

Comment: Odd, when trying to implement it now I am running into troubles. I specifically have an IEntity interface, IUndead, ILiving. So my list is of type IEntity, and I used to cast to IUndead and ILiving. Now I get a compiler error saying IEntity cannot convert to IUndead (it is derived from IEntity). Anyway, I don't expect you to resolve this, I just want to know if this solution still applies for interfaces? I suspect it should. I will test it myself though.

Comment: What's the full error ? I think it will say something along the lines of "an explicit cast exists blah blah" which means you tried to implicitly assign an IEntity to an IUndead (base -> derived). Try an explicit cast.

Comment: I found the error actually, but don't know how to fix it. It's a design error on my behalf. My interface IEntity does not have any processing methods of it's own. I chose to do this, as everything is by definition IEntity, but will also be something else, like IUndead or ILiving. Now it gives me a compile error as I did not handle the case where something is IEntity only (by my design this is never possible, yet there is no way for the compiler to know this). Perhaps I can suppress the error somehow?

Comment: Dumb suggestion. You cannot suppress errors, obviously. I guess I could put in empty functions that will never be called. Does this add any overhead, as there are now more overloaded versions of the function? Guess this is a triviality.

Comment: The ProcessExternal overloads won't have any affect in this case. It will always call ProcessExternal(A a). The test code shouldn't use the ToString method, but instead a string literal to see which method is being called.

Comment: @KellyEthridge 30 minutes ago I would agree with you. Though I have tested this and found that it works. The overload works. Wait... It doesn't :/ you are right.

Comment: @KellyEthridge do you mind explaining in more detail why Sniper's test case appears to work?

Comment: The ToString method returns the true type name(by default) of the object regardless of the interface used to call ToString. So A.ToString and B.ToString from the same B object will return the same value. So it just looked like it was being called from ProcessExternal(B b).

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by using the .Net 4.0 dynamic keyword. The example has been updated too to reflect what you said Kelly Ethridge, thanks !

Comment: The use of dynamic would be too slow here. I implemented a Double-Dispatch/Visitor pattern, which is efficient, fits well into my hierarchy structure, and does not require too much routine coding when expanding it to add more types.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest that you avoid the "if..else if..else if.." path by programming to interfaces instead of referencing concrete classes.

To achieve this, first make the `Process()` method ignorant of the type of its parameter. Probably the parameter will end up being an interface like `IDoSomething`.

Next, implement `Process()` so that it won't call `DoSomething()` directly. You'll have to break `DoSomething()` in smaller chunks of code which will be moved into specific implementations of `IDoSomething` methods. The `Process()` method will blindly call these methods -- in other words, applying the `IDoSomething` contract to some data.

This could be tiresome the more convoluted `DoSomething()` is, but you'll have a much better separation of concerns, and will "open" `Process()` to any `IDoSomething` compatible type, without writing not even one more `else`.

Comment: I like the idea of moving away from if...else / switch statements. I just became blind to staring at them.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to add a field in the base class specifying the class type.

```
    class A
    {
        // Alternative
        string typeName =  this.GetType().Name;
        public virtual string TypeName { get { return typeName; } }

        public virtual string GetTypeName() { return "A"; }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override string GetTypeName() { return "B"; }
    }

    class C : A
    {
        public override string GetTypeName() { return "C"; }
    }


    class Executer
    {

        void ExecuteCommand(A val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val.GetType().Name);

            switch (val.GetTypeName())
            {
                case "A": DoSomethingA(val as A); break;
                case "B": DoSomethingB(val as B); break;
                case "C": DoSomethingC(val as C); break;
            }
        }

        private void DoSomethingC(C c)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void DoSomethingB(B b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void DoSomethingA(A a)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

You don't really need to use strings, but I prefer that option to using integer for the simple reason that you can't declare 2 class with the same name in the same namespace, therefor if you always return the name class, you have an automatic anti conflict mechanism.

Comment: This definitely is an interesting solution. I will study it some more. I believe you can also replace the casts with as operators for better performance, as described by this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8052/Type-casting-impact-over-execution-performance-in . Check out the graph

Comment: :) nice. I used to use "as" cause I find it better looking :) Now I have a real reason. "as" doesn't work with struct though. You might also use the GetType function of object. Not sure how it would affect the performances, but it will certainly reduce the code length. Check out the alternative on the base class.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave this question open for another day or two to see what other interesting solutions come up, while I implement this. But I like your answer.