# Trying to get array of custom object types from array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a function that returns an array of objects.  The problem is, the objects can be one of three different types.  I am trying to break these objects into arrays of the different custom types.

For example:

```
var collection = something.ReturnObjArray();
var Details = collection.Where(a => a is DetailItem);
var Addenda = collection.Where(a => a is AddendaItem);
```

If i do the above and try to access the data in a foreach loop to put the Addenda in a collection within the Detail Items:

```
foreach (var addendaItem in Addenda)
{
    var detailItem = Details.Single(d => d.DetailAddendaKey == addendaItem.Key);
    detailItem.Addenda.Add(addendaItem);
}
```

I get errors like :

'object' does not contain a definition for 'DetailAddendaKey' and no extension method 'DetailAddendaKey' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Among others.   If i try and change the var for Details and Addenda to:

```
IEnumerable<DetailItem> Details = collection.Where(a => a is DetailItem);
IEnumerable<AddendaItem> Addenda = collection.Where(a => a is AddendaItem);
```

I get past the error above, but now get:

Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.DetailItem>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: what should be DetailAddendaKey? does this property belong to Detail class?

Comment: Yes.  It's how i was linking them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this sentence returns an object of type `object[]` (an object array):

```
var collection = something.ReturnObjArray();
```

`object` doesn't have the whole properties!

That's why `Details.Single(d => d.DetailAddendaKey == addendaItem.Key)` complains about that `d` doesn't have a property `DetailAddendaKey`.

You need to do this:

```
var Details = collection.Where(a => a is DetailItem).Cast<DetailItem>();
var Addenda = collection.Where(a => a is AddendaItem).Cast<AddendaItem>();
```

Or as @Mark Byers suggested (which is an abbreviation of above sample):

```
var Details = collection.OfType<DetailItem>();
var Addenda = collection.OfType<AddendaItem>();
```

This is downcasting all items in the `IEnumerable<object>` to `DetailItem` or `AddendaItem`, meaning that you'll have an `IEnumerable<DetailItem>` and `IEnumerable<AddendaItem>` after all!

Then, the next sentences will compile and work as you expect.

### Note

`OfType<T>()` should be a better choice since your approach of using `is` operator and later calling `Cast<T>()` is downcasting twice each object in the object array.

Check this other question and its answers for more info about `is` operator and its behavior:

- [C# 'is' operator performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686412/c-sharp-is-operator-performance)

Comment: That did it.  Mark's would have worked as well I'm sure.  I don't know why i didn't think of it.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<DetailItem> Details = collection.OfType<DetailItem>();
```