# How to set the Dropdownlist specific properties when traversing controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looping through the Controls collection of an asp:Panel, and I am not sure how to set Properties specific to some controls...

For example the Panel might contain a DropDownList, and I would like to be able to set and get the SelectedValue of this. Or it might contain a TextBox, and I would like to set and get the Text property.

I'm using this code to traverse:

```
foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
{
    // ...
}
```

And since I get just a Base Control from this, it appears not to be able to get/set any of these properties as they are not defined for the Base Control.

So, what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
foreach (Control control in Controls) {
    TextBox txt = control as TextBox;
    if (txt!=null) {
        txt.Text = "bla";
        ...
    }

    ComboBox cbo = control as ComboBox;
    if (cbo!=null) {
        cbo.SelectedItem = ...
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Note: If you have multiple controls of one type, you may use the [`Tag` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)  to store additional information. While `Tag` is of type object, you also need the `as` operator here...

Comment: Much better, would save one cast!

Comment: After researching "is", I agree that this is the best solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686412/c-sharp-is-operator-performance

Comment: Would this not create a new control for each control in the collection? What I want is to access the properties of the actual controls in the Controls collection.

Comment: No, it would not do that. Its only a reference.

Comment: @user866173: No: `TextBox txt = control as TextBox` is the same as `TextBox txt = control is TextBox ? (TextBox)control : null`. So it's like "Test if it's of Type X" and if true, "Cast to Type X" else "return null". Please see the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check the type, and then cast it to that type.

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
  if (control.GetType().Equals(typeof(DropDownList)))
  {
    ((DropDownList)control).Enabled = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `is` operator like so:

```
if(control is DropDownList)
{
    // Cast control as DDL and do your work
}
```