# c# casting with is and as

Tags: c#, .net

I need some help. It is pretty easy. I have this piece of code, and I would like to discuss if it is correct, or if you suggest a better way to do it. I have an idea about the answer but I would like to see your answers. here it goes

```
if (myObject is ClassA)
{
    var myObjectA = myObject as ClassA;
    myObjectA?.MethodJustInA();
}
else if (myObject is ClassB)
{
    var myObjectB = myObject as ClassB;
    myObjectB?.MethodJustInB();
    myObjectB?.OtherMethodJustInB();
}
```

I think there is no need to create a new object after every if, just doing:

```
(ClassB)myObjectB.MethodJustInB();
```

And there is no need to check it is null since if it is within the if is because is not null

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `as` if you already have checked the type, then you can cast it directly. The `as` operator comes in handy if the cast could fail which is impossible here.

Comment: *no need to create a new object*, your not, your casting an existing object. They are reference types and therefore mutable

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is it bad to not do so? Like, I can either do it like this: `(ClassA)myObject.MethodJustInB();`  or  `(myObject as ClassB).MethodJustInB();`. Whats the difference in that case?

Comment: You are not creating a new object by using as, and to call MethodJustInB you have to do it like this: ((ClassB)myObjectB).MethodJustInB();

Comment: `as` doesn´t create a new *object* but simply *references* an allready existing one.

Comment: StackOverflow isn´t the right place to *discus* good or bad practices.

Comment: @Cataklysim: what is _bad_? It is a little bit confusing because you suggest that you don't know if the type is really `ClassA` or `ClassB`. That's not true because you have checked it before. So someone else reading your code might try to safeguard this against `null`. Either use `as` with `null`-check or use `is` with explicit cast.

Answer (score 4):

There are some optimizations possible.

- If `myObject is ClassA`, you don't need the soft cast. Instead you can do the cast directly: `var myObjectA = (ClassA)myObject;`.
- Since that is the case, and you just call a single method, you don't need to assign a new variable: `((ClassA)myObject)?.MethodJustInA();`.
- And because `myObject is ClassA` evaluates to false if `myObject` is null, you don't need to do the check again: `((ClassA)myObject).MethodJustInA();`.

So:

```
if (myObject is ClassA)
{
    ((ClassA)myObject).MethodJustInA();
}
else if (myObject is ClassB)
{
    var myObjectB = (ClassB)myObject;
    myObjectB.MethodJustInB();
    myObjectB.OtherMethodJustInB();
}
```

Comment: But when using `is` you try to cast object to some type, after condition with `is` returns `true` you should cast second time. It is better to use `as` and then check for `null` - in this case you cast only time.

Comment: @Roma "when using is you try to cast object to some type" > not true. You test the type, a much simpler operation than casting and assigning.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686412/c-sharp-is-operator-performance/686431#686431 they say that `is` and `as` actually *do* the same things, at least in negative case, see comment by Konrad Rudolph.

Comment: Not sure if that is authoritative, but okay @HimBromBeere

Comment: me neither, I don´t know the IL which is created for an as-cast. For `is` it´s a call to `isinst` obviously. Apart from this I allways prefer to use the `as`cast and check for `null`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, you can see the IL code and you will see same operation are performed using `is` and `as`. Classes - http://prntscr.com/e6ia8a, IL generated - http://prntscr.com/e6ib6f

Comment: Indeed, the `isinst` does the `is` (so it seems `as` does `is` first), but `as` also does the assignment, what `is` doesn't. @Roma

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes, doing `if (myObject is ClassA)` you cast one time and then `((ClassA)myObject)` you cast second time. You can use `as` and check for `null` and it will be only one cast. But anyway, it is great answer.

Comment: Here we have a statement from Eric Lippert: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is/

Comment: So is is as @HimBromBeere

Comment: Obviously, because both perform `isinst` under the hood, but `as` also returns its value while `is` just ommits the casted value.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using it this way, you only need to cast it ones:

```
var myObjectA = (myObject as ClassA);

if (myObjectA != null)
{
    myObjectA.MethodJustInA();
} 
else
{
    var myObjectB = (myObject as ClassB);

    if (myObjectB != null)
    {
        myObjectB.MethodJustInB();
    }
}
```

And in C# 7.0 you can do:

```
if (myObject is ClassA myObjectA)
    myObjectA.MethodJustInA();
else 
    if (myObject is ClassB myObjectB)
        myObjectB.MethodJustInB();
```

Comment: You can change your code by `(myObject as ClassA)?.MethodJustInA();` without `if` statement

Comment: C# 7.0 offers the best solution to the case. Can't wait until it's live.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to cast with `as` and then check for `null`, this way you can skip the `is` check. Also, you do not need the elvis operator `?.` because you know the object is not null.

```
var myObjectA = myObject as ClassA;
var myObjectB = myObject as ClassB;
if (myObjectA != null)
{
    myObjectA.MethodJustInA();
}
else if (myObjectB != null)
{
    myObjectB.MethodJustInB();
    myObjectB.OtherMethodJustInB();
}
```

Comment: My experience is that this can get quite messy if you have more than a few possible types to check on, but generally a good solution.

Comment: Yes, with this pattern there might be some unnecessary casts and variables in the scope outside the if-else, for example if the first `if` evaluates to true, the cast to ClassB is not needed.

Comment: Indeed, you can still move the second cast to the `else`, but then you might end up with an endless of nested `if..else` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for multiple types, then `as`+`null` check is more *efficient* (just one cast, instead of `is` + casting):

```
var a = myObject as ClassA;
if (a != null)
    a.MethodJustInA();
var b = myObject as ClassB;
if (b != null)
    b.MethodJustInB();
```

In given scenario I'd even make local scope like this

```
{
    var obj = myObject as ClassA;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.MethodJustInA();
}
{
    var obj = myObject as ClassB;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.MethodJustInB();
}
```

`{ }` make it possible to reuse same variable name (easier to copy/paste and, in my oppinion, read).

---

I was a bit rushy and haven't thought well about `else` case (when `myObject is ClassA` you don't want to cast it as `b`, etc.). Normally I'd do `return` after each successful `if` and corresponding method call. I am not able to construct nice looking `if`/`else if` code otherwise.

---

Another idea is to use C# 6.0 null-conditional operator:

```
(myObject as ClassA)?.MethodJustInA();
(myObject as ClassB)?.MethodJustInB();
```

That looks really neat, but it will do unnecessarily casting to `B` and has side-effect: if `ClassB` inherits `ClassA`, then **both methods will be called** because both casts will success.

Note: mentioned side effect unfortunately applies to all proposed snippets.

Comment: The local scoping might give problems when `ClassB` derives `ClassA`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, `OP` uses `else if` (in his case that would be a problem too), but you are right, also see edit. My answer is not the best, but I don't think your is *ideal* too ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman, wait, do you mean what it will successfully calls **both** methods? Yep, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Within those `if` statements you can just cast your object like this:

```
var myObjectB = (ClassB)myObject;
```

or cast it directly:

```
((ClassB)myObject).MethodJustInB();
```