# iterating through generic type T if T is IEnumerable without cast

Tags: c#, generics, casting

The following code would compile if `foo` is casted to either a type implementing `IEnumerable` or `dynamic`. Is there a way to achieve the same without casting `foo` ? 
I am aware I could do two methods and don't wish to force more constraint to T.

```
interface IDummy
{}

class FooBar<T> where T : class
{
    void Bar(T foo)
    {
       if (foo is IEnumerable<IDummy>)
          foreach (var item in foo)
             B(item);
       else if(foo is IDummy)
          B(foo);                      
    }  

    void B(IDummy item)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Using generics doesn't solve anything here.  Just have `Bar` accept an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to iterate over an object that may or may not be an `IEnumerable`. The only way to do that is to cast the object as an `IEnumerable` and if the cast succeeds, iterate. You could do that a bit easier using `if (foo is IEnumerable fooE) foreach (var item in fooE)` if you're using C# 7 or above.

Comment: @Amy I edited to provide a more intent with a use of genericity. I focused too much on doing a minimal dummy code.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that without casting `foo` or enforcing a constraint `where T : IEnumerable`. You'll get a compile error if you try to pass a type to the `foreach` statement that isn't guaranteed to be an `IEnumerable` (or doesn't have a the public parameterless `GetEnumerator()` method whose return type is a class, struct, or interface).

Comment: Anytime you find yourself checking the type of `T` in a generic method, it's likely not a great candidate for generics.

Comment: Generics that perform type tests internally are *usually* a bad idea. So, you've promised me that `FooBar` can work with any reference type. I then write a perfectly legal call to `A` having parameterized with a type that is neither `IEnumerable` nor `Dummy`. The method, far from working, does nothing. Even if it throws a runtime exception, you've "lied" to me and the compiler about what types you can *actually* work with.

Comment: If someone should be able to either pass in an `IDummy` or an `IEnumerable<IDummy>` then *have two overloads, with each of those two types as parameters*, so that callers know those are the two types your method accepts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Great answer :)

Comment: It's also a minefield. Suppose I define `class Abc: IDummy, IEnumerable<IDummy> {...}`. In my mind, it's an `IDummy` first and foremost and contains an `IEnumerable<IDummy>` secondarily. I can't use your generic as declared if I want the `IDummy` behaviour. At least with overloads, I can cast away it's concreteness and get the call I want/need.

Comment: (And whilst I can do the same by parameterizing by `IDummy` or `IEnumerable<IDummy>` with the generic version, why was it generic anyway if I have to only use interfaces?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your reasons are for not wanting to cast, but would something like this work for you?

```
interface IDummy
{}

class FooBar<T> where T : class
{
    void Bar(T foo)
    {
       if (foo is IEnumerable<IDummy> enumerableFoo)
          foreach (var item in enumerableFoo)
             B(item);
       else if(foo is IDummy)
          B(foo);                      
    }  

    void B(T item)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the compilation error on `B(item)` (which is my fault, B signature is wrong), isn't this just syntaxic sugar for `IEnumerable<IDummy> enumerableFoo = foo as IEnumerable<IDummy>;` so still a cast ?

Comment: Yes basically. Just thought I'd suggest it since using "is" was not a stopper for you.  Out of curiosity, why do you not want to cast foo?

Comment: Is was not a stopper because I believed is operator is syntaxic sugar for `foo.GetType() == typeof(T)`, so no cast. Am I wrong ?

The whole question is purely out of curiosity. Any sane code would use method overload (which doesn't use cast indeed)

Comment: No you're right, no cast there even though they are not completely the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is).  Indeed an interesting question, I don't have the answer then I'm afraid.

Comment: See also this performance comparison of the is operator vs type comparison.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11518994/1056639

Comment: @Baguette CIL has a command `isinst` that the is operator maps to, so it is better/different than the type comparison equality check.